# Merging tuples in list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, combinatorics

Say there is a list of tuples where in each tuple can only contain unique characters/numbers and the order and length of each tuple is the same. like this, a list of tuples of `(1, 2, 3)` :

```
l = [
    (1   ,    2,    3), #1  
    (None,    2,    3), #2 merge with #4 or #8
    (1   , None,    3), #3 merge with #6
    (1   , None, None), #4 overhead?
    (1   ,    2,    3), #5
    (None,    2, None), #6
    (1   ,    2, None), #7 overhead
    (1   , None, None), #8 overhead?
    ]
```

But in some tuples values are missing and the missing values should be merged/ complemented with matching tuples from the same list. 
After merging, if any tuples are over that still contain a None value, they should be cut off or appended at the end.

**Designated Result:**

```
l = [
    (1   ,    2,    3), #1  
    (1   ,    2,    3), #2 merged with #4
    (1   ,    2,    3), #3 merged with #6
    (1   ,    2,    3), #4
    ]
```

Is there any way in python to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what's the conflict resolution strategy? if `1, 2, 3` , `None, None, 3` and `2, None, 3` how do you pick the values of the second tuple?

Comment: also is a complement tuple to a tuple with missing values guaranteed to exist?

Comment: I think that last tuple in your result should be `#5`. Are all the complete or completed tuples guaranteed to be identical, or could there be more variety? Could more than two tuples be merged, such as `(1, None, None)`, `(None, 2, None)`, and `(None, None, 3)`?

Comment: Python is Turing-complete, so there is a way to do this in Python. What attempts have you made at a solution, and just where are you stuck? We want to see more of your work.

Comment: sort them in order of none Eg first 1 2 3, N 2 3,  1 N 3, 1 2 N, N N 3, N 2 N, 1 N N, N N N. Now 1 Ns can go with only 2 Ns so compare those keeping two pointers

Comment: @RoryDaulton good point, yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this nested list comprehension using zip:

```
list(zip(*[[f for f in e if f] for e in zip(*l)]))
```

Outputs:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```